# f.seek() reads extra Linebreak or space in python

Tags: python

```
with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    print(f.tell())     # output : 0
    print(f.read(1))    # output : A

    f.seek(1)
    print(f.read(1))    # output : B

    f.seek(5)  
    print(f.read(1))    # output : D

    f.seek(14)
    print(f.read(1))    # output :  ?????

    f.seek(15)
    print(f.read(1))    # output : J
```

**text.txt**

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
```

**Output**

```
0
A
B
D


J
```

I couldn't understand output of `f.read(1)` for `f.seek(14)` and `f.seek(15)` because I was expecting `K` and `L`

It seems  on top of one `\n`,  Either extra `\n` or `space` is generated between `F` and `G`, `I` and `J` But Not generated between `C` and `D`

So why output is like this and what happend ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you notice that there is a space before each `\n` in your `text.txt`? If you remove the spaces, the result will be

```
0
A
B
E
L
```

Edited:
you might also want to check if the newline is `\r\n`(in Windows) or `\n`. If the newline is `\r\n`, you get the wrong result as well.

Comment: Im using windows , So  I think new line is `\r\n` as you said. So Now how can I get my expected result? (still I need linebreak `\n`)

Comment: @Kazu25 Could you be more specific about what you want to achieve? If you want the result to become `0\nA\nB\nE\nL\n`, you need to rewrite `text.txt`. If you want to process the files without caring about which type of newline is used(either `\r\n` or `\n`), you can just call `readlines` to read each line, since [universal newlines](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) is already supported in [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) in Python3.